# Is there a way to avoid nativescript activity lifecycle events to be triggered more than once

Tags: activity-lifecycle, nativescript-angular

I try to handle the android lifecycle in my NativeScript android app using the following guide:
https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/application-lifecycle#android-activity-events

When i use the back button to quit the app and then the recent button to reopen the app, all the lifecycle events are triggered twice. If i do ti again, all the lifecycle events are triggered thrice.

Here is a playground simple app that shows the problem:
https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=y9RucD

Use the back button and then the recent button to resume...

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove listeners on destroy event. As you are using `android.on` to assign the event listeners, you need to use the `android.off` as well.

You can find the a complete example [here](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-sdk-examples-js/blob/master/app/ns-framework-modules-category/application/application-events/application-events-ts-page.ts#L41-L91) and [here](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/7154#issuecomment-483953568). I have also updated the your [playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=y9RucD&v=2).

In your ngOnInit function I am assigning android.on to a listener e.g.

```
this.launchListenerCB = (args) => {
            console.log(">>>>>>> resumeEvent Event");
            if (args.android) {
                // For Android applications, args.android is an android.content.Intent class.
                console.log("resumeEvent Android application with the following intent: " + args.android + ".");
            }
        };

        appOn(resumeEvent, this.launchListenerCB);
```

and on exitEvent I am unsubscribing to all listeners.

```
this.exitListenerCB = (eventData: any) => {

            this.unsubscribeAll();
        }
        appOn(exitEvent, this.exitListenerCB);



private unsubscribeAll(): void {
        // console.log("unsubscribeAll launchListenerCB:", !!launchListenerCB)

        appOff(resumeEvent, this.launchListenerCB); // HERE
        // appOff(suspendEvent, this.suspendListenerCB);
        // appOff(resumeEvent, this.resumeListenerCB);
        // appOff(lowMemoryEvent, this.lowMemoryListenerCB);
        // appOff(exitEvent, this.exitListenerCB);
    }
```

In your playground, I have just used ResumeEvent to show you the code, you can assign/unassign to other events as well.

Comment: It works like a charm, thank you very much  for helping me understanding that obviously, if i subscribe, i have to unsubscribe.
Sorry for waiting so long to answer. Better late than never.

Comment: say, why `this` doesn't exists inside the new event ? ( i.e: `this.zone` is undefined` )

Comment: @RickyLevi you have call the callback within an arrow function so `this` is the same. So instead of `appOn(resumeEvent, this.launchListenerCB) ` you have to do `appOn(resumeEvent, () => this.launchListenerCB())`, so `this` will be the same as in the component.